# NodeJS, Joi Validation - Abort execution upon failed validation

Tags: node.js, error-handling, header, send, joi

I have the following code:

```
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
            zip: Joi.number().min(1).max(9999999).required().label("Just an example error code, avoid the zip code validation method (0-9999999)."),
        });

        Joi.validate({ zip: req.body.zip }, schema, function (err, value) {
            if (!(err === null)){
                res.status(400).send(err['details']['0']['context']['label']);
            }
        });
```

Even when I successfully invoke the error message, and get it to be sent back to me in the HTTP header (error 400), the execution just won't stop and will keep on running.
I assume that this happens because it already skips to the other parts of execution and doesn't even get to the part where it returns the headers error message.

How can I avoid it? Will the only way for me to avoid it will be to use the Joi dependency with callbacks / promises / async, await?

If no, how can I implement the Joi dependency with Promises in the best possible way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:
While sending back a response using:
`res.status(400).send(err['details']['0']['context']['label']);`

I realised I didn't use the return statement in-order to make it "final". Adding it solved the problem, as follows:

`return res.status(400).send(err['details']['0']['context']['label']);`